# Seating people around a table (elementary counting technique)

Tags: combinatorics

Eight people, including Abigail and Bethany, are to be seated at a square table so that two people are along each edge. Two seatings are considered distinct if, and only if, the ordering of people starting with Abigail and continuing clockwise around the table in one seating is distinct from that in the other seating.  How many distinct seatings are there so that Abigail and Bethany are not next to nor across from each other?

There are 8!/8 = 7! seatings of the eight people around the table. There are 2(7!/7) = 2(6!) seatings with Abigail and Bethany next to each other, and there are 2(7!/7) = 2(6!) seatings with Abigail and Bethany across from each other. So, there
\begin{equation*}
7! - 2(6!) - 2(6!) = 2160
\end{equation*}
seatings in which Abigail and Bethany are not next to nor across from each other.

I am using the Complement Principle.  Is this correct?

Comment: It depends on the meaning of next to each other. If it means "and on the same edge" then your first $2(6!)$ should just be $6!$. If A and B are considered  to be neighbours even if they are not on the same edge, but around a corner from each other, then the $2(6!)$ is right.

Comment: @andreNicolas Hmm I didn't consider that one. On the other hand I interpreted across in a different way I guess.

Comment: I think across should be interpreted as directly across, facing each other if sitting normally.

Comment: @André Nicolas  Yes, Andre, your interpretation of "across" is correct - I mean "directly across."  Also, to say that "Abigail and Bethany are not next to each other" means that going in either direction from Abigail, Bethany is not the next person.

Comment: @DRF  Yes, your interpretation, as stated in your solution, of "across" is what is intended.  "I chose to interpret it as the situation where a line connecting to the two people is perpendicular to an axis of symmetry of the table."  I interpret "axis of symmetry" as either a horizontal line or a vertical line through the center of the rectangular table.

Comment: We seem to agree on the default interpretation of "across."  As I mentioned, "next to" has two possible interpretations. Maybe here the default is the round table sense,but I am less sure.

Comment: @André Nicolas  I want to confirm my solution if "next to" has the interpretation as in "the round table sense,."

Comment: Yes, we subtract  $2\cdot 6!$ for the next to.  And for the across, there are essentially $2$ positions for A, then B is determined, and $6!$ for the rest, so we subtract another $2\cdot 6!$.

Comment: @André Nicolas  Thanks.  I got this problem from Ralph Grimaldi's textbook Discrete and Combinatorial Mathematics.  I think that he was just making a slight variation of the usual situation of people seated around a table.

Answer (score 1):

The way I read the problem I think you are subtracting $2(6!)$ one too many times. Unrolling the argument I suppose it should look like the following.

Since you don't actually care which side of the table anyone is sitting at, (Since two seatings are the same if the ordering starting with Abigail and going clockwise is different) you can pretty much model your seating arrangements by thinking of the ordering only. Given that there are 7! choices for the ordering (since we can fix Abigail to be the first), which you got. Then you can seat Bethany next to her on the left or the right that's one $2(6!)$.

Now we need to deal with the situations of sitting across form each other. The issue here is that if you seat the people $A,\_,\_,B,\_,\_,\_,\_$ then this is a valid seating arrangement since you can place $A$ on the left corner of the table in which case $B$ is not sitting across from them. Same situation is when you get $A, \_ , \_ , \_ , B , \_ , \_ , \_ $ in which case you can seat $A$ on the right corner of the table and $B$ is not across. Thus if you only care about the order of the guests clockwise from $A$ then the only cases that need to be excluded are the ones when $A$ and $B$ are next to each other. The ones where they are across from each other can still be valid seating arrangements by rotating them.

Note: this does depend how one interprets sitting across.

I chose to interpret it as the situation where a line connecting to the two people is perpendicular to an axis of symettry of the table.

Comment: When people are seated at a rectangular table, they are seated (typically) along the edges.  To be sure that there wouldn't be any misunderstanding, I stated the situation as "Eight people, including Abigail and Bethany, are to be seated at a square table so that two people are 'along each edge'."